# Can not download dependencies for SBT (the build tool for Scala) in the first run

Tags: scala, dependencies, installation, sbt

As you must known, the first time you run SBT, it starts to download his dependencies:

```
>sbt sbt-version
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.12.4
downloading repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/main/0.12.4/jars/main.jar ...
```

The problem is that I'm living in Africa and the ISP is not very good: for some unknown reason, they are some domains from which I can not download any file. For example, if I enter to the site of WAMP and try to download the installer, the download begins but it never ends. Normally I fix this issue by using a proxy (such as HideMyAss or ZendProxy), which servers as an intermediate between the site and the ISP, allowing me of download the file.

typesafe.com seems to be one of the not-work-for-download-in-africa domains, as consequence, SBT can not download his dependencies.

**The question is, there is a way of download manually the dependencies?** (I have downloaded them using a proxy, but I do not known in which folder put them in order to avoid SBT to try to download them)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a directory in the root of your sbt project called `lib` and put the jars there.

Comment: By the moment I have not any project, I'm just executing the sentence "sbt sbt-version" from the command prompt of Windows 8

Comment: Then just pick a directory where you like to begin working. The important part is you have the lib directory in the same directory in which you are executing sbt.

Comment: I created the "lib" folder in the installation directory of SBT and then I picked this directory as the working directory in the command prompt, and it worked! Thanks

Comment: Nice! Have fun with Scala!